# How to fix Warning about React.forwardRef() after update Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

After updating Ant to version 3.16.6, console shows this warning:

> Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref
>   will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

**This appear only when my child component is wrapped in `form.getFieldDecorator()`. Case without `getFieldDecorator()` works successfully.**
PS: My child component is not a Function Component, it's statefull.

In the past, I had version 3.11.0 and it worked fine.

The code is a simple case, not much:

HOC

```
[...]
render() { 
    return (
        <>
            <Form.Item>                                         
                {form.getFieldDecorator('descricaoUnidadeTrabalho', {rules})(
                    <MyChild 
                        props={props} 
                        onChange={id => form.setFieldsValue({ id })}
                    />
                )}
            </Form.Item>
        </>
    )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    Form.create()(MyComponent)
);
```

Child Component

```
[...]
render() {
    return (
        <Select props>
            <Select.Option key={id} value={id}>
                {value}
            </Select.Option>
        </Select>
    ); 
}
export default MyChild;
```

What can go wrong in my case, could you please advise me?

Answer (score 2):

`getFieldDecorator` forwards `ref` to its children components.

In your case, it tries to forward `ref` to `MyChild`, but you didn't implement it in your component.

That's why you need to use `forwardRef`, possible solution:

```
const MyChild = React.forwardRef(({ onChange, ...props }, ref) => (
  <Select {...props} ref={ref}>
    <Select.Option key={id} value={id}>
      {value}
    </Select.Option>
  </Select>
));

export default MyChild;
```

Note calling an attribute as `props` is very confusing and error-prone.